# If I scrap a locked safe, does its content go to the workshop?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, when using the workshop in a settlement you can scrap containers. If you do so while they still contain something their content go to the workshop inventory (according to comments on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/242932/27271)).

But you can also scrap locked safes. If you do so, does the content also go to the workshop inventory, negating the need to unlock the safe ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. If you scrap a locked safe the contents of that safe are then transferred to your workshop, negating the need to unlock the safe.

Comment: You do lose the XP from unlocking it though, correct? (as well as any trophy/achievement-related benefit I suppose)

Comment: By "lose" I should clarify that I meant that you wont gain it in the first place.

Comment: Yes you would, but in no case was I able to scrap a safe until it was picked first.  The safe outline does not highlight until it's unlocked.  All unlocked containers with contents do get sent to your workshop, including unlocked safes.

Comment: I was a able to scrap an Advanced safe in Sanctuary without unlocking it-- at the time I hadn't even trained Locksmith at all.

Comment: There's a safe in the back of the drive-in that i was unable to scrap before opening

Comment: There should be a message on the screen saying that the container's contents have been transferred to the workshop.