# Where do I find bobbleheads, after benching the bobblehead stand?

Tags: fallout-4

I had a full bobblehead stand, and I put it in my workshop. However, now I can not find my bobbleheads. Even the bonuses are gone.

Perhaps it is a glitch, but where can I find my bobbleheads?

Comment: _"Even the bonuses are gone."_ Are you sure on this point? Do you have any of the bobbleheads that boost your SPECIAL stats? If so, did your SPECIAL stats go back down after this happened?

Answer (score 8):

The bobbleheads are stored separately, under the "misc" section of the workshop inventory.

Go to a workbench, in the settlement where you stored your bobblehead stand. Press the button for the "transfer" prompt, then navigate to the "misc" section.

You should be able to retrieve your bobbleheads from there.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the bobbleheads will just get stored as seperate items, under the "misc" section?

Comment: @Timelord64 Yes. I just did it in my own game, and it lists all the bobbleheads under the "Misc" section of the workshop inventory.

Comment: @Timelord64 I appreciate the edit for clarification. Though I do want to point out that "Bobblehead" is one word in the game menus and item descriptions, which is why I wrote it as such.

Comment: your right. Bobble head comes up as the correct spelling, but they are called bobbleheads, in game. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Yup, this is correct. The bobblehead stand acts similarly as any 'container' item in your settlement. If you scrap/store the container, all its contents are stored in the workbench, as also detailed in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/244146/if-i-scrap-a-locked-safe-does-its-content-go-to-the-workshop).